# lambda@edge not getting triggered with cloudfront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I am using lambda@edge to redirect my sites with cloudfront.

I have attached my versioned lambda arn to my cloud front cache behavior to all 4 events it has.

when i hit my cloudfront endpoint it says

```
502 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
The Lambda function returned invalid json: The json output must be an object type.
```

when i check my lambda logs / invocation metrics i dont see any hits at all .

what may be the reason behind this ?

i tried my best to find the fix why my lambda is not getting triggered ??

Comment: Clearly, from the error, **your function is being triggered**.  It is returning an invalid response, which CloudFront rejects and renders as a `502 Bad Gateway` error.  Please show your code.

Comment: You will find the logs and metrics in the region nearest the edge that is closest to the viewer -- not necessarily us-east-1.  Lambda@Edge is globally distributed and runs the functions closer to where they are requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i missed adding region under the header in my lambda code.

since lambda@edge runs in the edge location we need to mention the region dynamically so that it knows where to write the logs when its running in the nearest edge location.

```
'x-lae-region': [ { key: 'x-lae-region', value: process.env.AWS_REGION } ]

const response = {
        status: '302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: 'http://<destinationdomainname>/goto/hello.html',
            }],
            'x-lae-region': [ { key: 'x-lae-region', value: process.env.AWS_REGION } ],
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 17):

There are some common "gotchas" to Lambda@Edge and CloudFront. You need to:

- Publish a new version of you Lambda function
- Update the CloudFront Lambda association to your new version, e.g. `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:572007530218:function:gofaas-WebAuthFunction:45`
- Look for Lambda@Edge logs in the region of the **requestor**

This is different from "normal" Lambda web console flow of saving a code change and jumping to logs from the monitoring tab.

Comment: What does "Update the CloudFront Lambda association" mean? I'm having this problem and still not sure what I'm missing. In Lambda I published a new version, then added a CloudFront trigger. I don't see anywhere to "Update the CloudFront Lambda association." Is that in the CloudFront console somewhere?

Comment: This property in CloudFormation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-lambdafunctionassociation.html

Comment: Thanks! For me the issue was that I was looking at the region of the originally deployed lambda, not the region closest to the requester :)

Comment: For me, I needed to look at the region the CloudFront request ran on (not the actual lambda function region). Reason is, CloudFront does edge (distributed across regions) traffic.